# Solving 3-variable recurrence involving binomial coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence:
$$B_m(n+1,k) = kB_m(n,k)+B_m(n,k-1)-{n\choose m} B_m(n-m,k)$$
where $n,k,m\geq 1$ are integers.

We have boundary conditions 
\begin{align}
B_m(n,n)&=1
\\B_m(n,k)&=0 \qquad n<k
\\B_m(n,k)&=0 \qquad mk<n 
\end{align}
and some others.

**What I tried:** Use exponential generating functions w.r.t $m$ to get rid of the binomial coefficient. Let $A$ be the egf $\{B_m\}_1^\infty$. Doing this gets (I think)
$$A'(n+1,k) = kA(n,k) + A(n,k-1) - e^x A(n,k)$$

This gives a 2 variable recurrence with a derviative. My thoughts are to use generating functions again to be left with one variable but I'm not sure how to do that with the derivative here.

Thanks.